# How to analyze build and test step in different stages using sonarQube?

Tags: .net, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

My build step and test steps are in two different stages in my Jenkins pipeline but from the sonarQube [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/), it seems the build and test command needs to be in the same block of code. Is there any way I could do the build and test in different pipeline stages with sonarQube analysis tool? I have the following structure in my Jenkinsfile

```
node {
    stage('checkout code from git') {
        cleanWs()
        checkout scm
    }
    
    stage('Build') {
    def buildVersion = "1.0.0.1"
        withSonarQubeEnv('mySonarQubeScanner') 
        {
            sh "dotnet-sonarscanner begin /k:'TestProject' /d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths='unit_tests.xml'"     
            
            sh "dotnet restore testProject/testProject.csproj -p:Version=$buildVersion -p:FileVersion=$buildVersion -p:AssemblyVersion=$buildVersion"
            sh "dotnet publish testProject/testProject.csproj --output bin/application/testApp --configuration Release -p:Version=$buildVersion -p:FileVersion=$buildVersion -p:AssemblyVersion=$buildVersion"
        
            sh "dotnet-sonarscanner end"
        }
    }
    
    stage('test) {
        sh "dotnet restore testProject.Test/testProject.Test.csproj"
        sh "dotnet test --configuration Release --logger \"trx;LogFileName=unit_tests.xml\" testProject.Test"
    }
}
```

As mentioned earlier, I would like to keep the same structure of my pipeline to be able to see the test coverage report but I do not know how to achieve that now since I have two stages.

Comment: I would not call `dotnet-sonarscanner end` until everything is done. So most probably make 4 stages: sonarqube-prepare, build, test, sonarqube-end.

Comment: would this work even though we are closing the `withSonarQubeEnv ` block in the build stage?

Comment: You can have more than one `withSonarQubeEnv`. It's only needed for `begin` and `end` steps of sonarscanner. When this closure ends, it will try to find out sonar report, so for the first call you may want to add `envOnly: true` to skip this behavior (https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJNKNS-322, code: https://github.com/jenkinsci/sonarqube-plugin/blob/1bade4ab6ad3076bdf66d5537e72ba0c0a728355/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/sonar/SonarBuildWrapper.java#L115)

Comment: I only work with Java and Javascript builds, and with scripted pipelines, not declarative, but when it comes down to it, SonarQube needs to have all of the source AND binary artifacts to be present during the scan. It doesn't matter if the build and scan are in the same stages, you just have to make sure you don't delete things between stages.

Comment: @raspy I tried using `envOnly: true` but I keep getting an error when I run the pipeline `Expected named arguments but got [{envOnly=true}, mySonarQubeScanner]`. I don't know why I am getting this exception.

Comment: @Leroi did you ever figure out the `envOnly: true` problem? As I am facing the same issue now.

Comment: Adding to my comment of 28 minutes ago, apparently the proper syntax is `withSonarQubeEnv(installationName: 'My SonarQube Server', envOnly: true) {`